# PHPUnit + Symfony, entities mocking

Tags: symfony, unit-testing

I have a problem with testing my app.
Here is the Repository:

```
class DocumentRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{
    public function getDocuments($type)
    {
        switch($type)
        {
            case 'invoices':
                $where = "WHERE d.type = 'FV'";
                break;
            case 'bills':
                $where = "WHERE d.type = 'Rachunek'";
                break;
            default:
                $where = "";
                break;
        }
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery("SELECT
                    d.number,
                    d.type
                FROM
                    ApiBundle:Document d".$where)
        ->getArrayResult();
    }
}
```

Controller class:

```
class DocumentController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * @Route("/list/{type}")
    * @Method({"GET"})
    */
    public function documentListAction($type = 'all')
    {
        $documents = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('ApiBundle:Document')
            ->getDocuments($type);

        $response = new JsonResponse();
        return $response->setData($documents);
    }
}
```

And here is the test:

```
public function testDocument()
{
        $document = $this->createMock(Document::class);
        $document->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getNumber')
            ->will($this->returnValue('FV 00/00/0000'));
        $document->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getType')
            ->will($this->returnValue('FV'));


        $documentRepository = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(EntityRepository::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $documentRepository->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getDocuments')
            ->will($this->returnValue($document));


        $entityManager = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(ObjectManager::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $entityManager->expects($this->once())
            ->method('getRepository')
            ->will($this->returnValue($documentRepository));

        $documentController = new DocumentController($entityManager);
}
```

When I start the test, then I always see alerts, warnings and errors.
I do not know a lot about app testing, and I have no idea, that the test write is good.

I want to learn how to test, but I have a problem with mock entities. It will be fine if someone give me some tips about that. I rarely ask a questions in the internet about the programming, I always solve the problems by myself with use the internet, but now I have no longer the strength. In this app i use JWT too, but for tests, I disabled authentication.

I will be grateful for your help.

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test?

Comment: That the return JSON is equals to JSON string

Comment: So it's a controller, is it? You probably need a functional test, which is described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#functional-tests

Comment: And then must I insert appropriate data, to database?

Comment: And tests may be dependent by database?

Comment: Yes, it would be an end-to-end-test. Your controller is dependent on DIC, therefore it's hard to test it in a unit test in the way you're thinking. You would need to define your controller as service and pass dependencies via constructor in order to be able to test it this way.

Comment: Ok, now i understand all. Thank you for help.